# What is use of Yarn/any queue while executing spark-submit?

Tags: apache-spark, queue, bigdata

I am trying to understand why do we need to give a queue while executing spark-submit? What role does it play and why is needed and how is it used? I am trying to understand spark and relatively new to it. So please point me if there is an answer/explanation already

PS: Couldn't find any proper explanation for the above question and thus posting in this community

Comment: What queue you are talking about? spark.yarn.queue?
I see only the queue parameter in YARN mode. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html#launching-spark-on-yarn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about the queue parameter in [YARN mode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html#spark-properties) then it is

`The name of the YARN queue to which the application is submitted.`
To get more details about the subject you can look at:

- https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/CapacityScheduler.html
- https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.5/bk_yarn-resource-management/content/setting_up_queues.html
- https://blog.cloudera.com/yarn-capacity-scheduler/

But in general, the YARN queue is just a way to isolate resource usage between different processes.